# Firefox Developer edition 48.0 crashes after update

Tags: crash, ubuntu-14.04, firefox-developer-edition

I'm using the Developer edition of Firefox in Ubuntu 14.04.

Yesterday, I update it (just some translation packages, I think) and today it's not opening anymore.

Click in the firefox icon does not produce any result or error, the browser just doesn't open.

Trying to start it from CLI (even with sudo) return the following error:

```
[7031] ###!!! ABORT: JS_InitWithFailureDiagnostic: u_init() failed:
file /build/firefox-W4cjM_/firefox-48.0~a2~hg20160509r318685/xpcom/build/XPCOMInit.cpp, line 709
[7031] ###!!! ABORT: JS_InitWithFailureDiagnostic: u_init() failed: file /build/firefox-W4cjM_/firefox-48.0~a2~hg20160509r318685/xpcom/build/XPCOMInit.cpp, line 709
Segmentation fault
```

Googling for any solution , I found this [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1264836) from some months ago, but without any solution. Looks like not the same problem, since my computer is a little endian system (Linux on x86).

I already tried `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get autoremove` without success.

Anyone has a idea of how to fix it?

MISC

> - Ubuntu 14.04 (32 bit)
> - Mozilla Firefox 48.0a2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem in Ubuntu 15.10.

Assuming you're installing from the Aurora Daily ppa
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-aurora

There may be a fix in the next update, later today.

I've raised bugs:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1272246

In the meantime the package at the FireFox Developer page works if you install manually

First remove you current FF and PPA

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
```

Then install manually:

Instructions here https://askubuntu.com/questions/548003/how-do-i-install-the-firefox-developer-edition#answers

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/532943)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I've updated my answer with a work around, any better?

Comment: Bug has been confirmed with Ubuntu launchpad, affecting multiple users https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1580919

Comment: Also occurs in 16.04 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1272246

Comment: Yes that looks much more like an answer. Thanks for taking the trouble to make those improvements

Comment: The new update do the trick! Thanks for your response.